# how to find the Column number of the string

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line-interface

I want to find the column number of the string "net5-dummy1"

```
openstack server list | grep testserver01
```

Output:

```
| b2bcd3bd-a787-1c22-c0da-de98a7bek7788 | work-scc3-n3kdi955-scc01ltnmmk | ACTIVE | -          | Running     | net1-gw=10.70.1.11; net2-calico=10.71.22.12; net3-traffic=10.72.23.13;  net4-trunk=171.16.8.12; net5-dummy1=171.19.8.12; net6-dummy2=10.88.8.25
```

Above output, need to find the column number of `net5-dummy1`. Kindly help me to identify the column number.

Thanks

Comment: @markp-fuso always looking at my question and gives negative reviews. Good keep doing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your columns are speratated by `|`, you could do:

```
#!/bin/bash

input="| b2bcd3bd-a787-1c22-c0da-de98a7bek7788 | work-scc3-n3kdi955-scc01ltnmmk | ACTIVE | -          | Running     | net1-gw=10.70.1.11; net2-calico=10.71.22.12; net3-traffic=10.72.23.13;  net4-trunk=171.16.8.12; net5-dummy1=171.19.8.12; net6-dummy2=10.88.8.25"

colnum=$(echo "$input" | tr '|' '\n'  | grep -n "net5-dummy1" | cut -d':' -f1)
(( colnum -= 1 ))
echo "$colnum"
```

- Here I substract 1 to the the `grep -n` value since the first column is not the empty column before the first `|`, I think.

---

Or if you also want to split columns on `|` **and** `;`, you can do:

```
#!/bin/bash

input="| b2bcd3bd-a787-1c22-c0da-de98a7bek7788 | work-scc3-n3kdi955-scc01ltnmmk | ACTIVE | -          | Running     | net1-gw=10.70.1.11; net2-calico=10.71.22.12; net3-traffic=10.72.23.13;  net4-trunk=171.16.8.12; net5-dummy1=171.19.8.12; net6-dummy2=10.88.8.25"

colnum=$(echo "$input" | tr '|' '\n'  | tr ';' '\n' | grep -n "net5-dummy1" | cut -d':' -f1)
(( colnum -= 1 ))
echo "$colnum"
```